# Difference between min/max clearance and min/max tolerance and relation between them

Tags: tolerance

Recently I have seen a question as follows:

Dimension of the hole is $50 +.02/-.00$ mm and shaft is $50 +.02/-.00$ mm.The minimum clearance is?

My answer is .00 but the correct answer as per the website is -.02

Where am I going wrong?

Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimum clearance occurs when the largest possible shaft meets the smallest possible hole. That would be in this case a shaft of $50.02 mm$ in a hole of $50.00 mm$. The difference between the two is the $-0.02 mm$ from the solution you found.

Comment: That would be an interference fit...